# Add titles to ggplots created with map()

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

What's the easiest way to add titles to each ggplot that I've created below using the map function? I want the titles to reflect the name of each data frame - i.e. 4, 6, 8 (cylinders).

Thanks :)

```
mtcars_split <- 
  mtcars %>%
  split(mtcars$cyl)

plots <-
  mtcars_split %>%
  map(~ ggplot(data=.,mapping = aes(y=mpg,x=wt)) + 
        geom_jitter() 
  # + ggtitle(....))

plots
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `map2` with `names`.

```
plots <- map2(
  mtcars_split,
  names(mtcars_split),
  ~ggplot(data = .x, mapping = aes(y = mpg, x = wt)) + 
    geom_jitter() +
    ggtitle(.y)
)
```

Edit: alistaire pointed out this is the same as `imap`

```
plots <- imap(
  mtcars_split,
  ~ggplot(data = .x, mapping = aes(y = mpg, x = wt)) + 
    geom_jitter() +
    ggtitle(.y)
)
```

Comment: @alistaire, yes - forgot about imap. I've updated my answer to include imap.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you'd be interested in using `facet_wrap` instead

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y=mpg, x=wt)) + geom_jitter() + facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `purrr::map2()`:

```
mtcars_split <- mtcars %>% split(mtcars$cyl)

plots <- map2(mtcars_split, titles, 
  ~ ggplot(data=.x, aes(mpg,wt)) + geom_jitter() + ggtitle(.y)
)
```

**EDIT**

Sorry duplicated with **Paul's** answer.