# How to use map and ggplot to add custom titles to each chart?

Tags: r, function, loops, ggplot2, purrr

I have a dataset that I want to make simple bar charts for each variable that has their appropriate title by using map() from purrr.

My dataset has 4 variables, and I have a vector with 4 titles. How do I pass these titles through so R outputs a plot that has the appropriate title for each? For my end result, I want 4 plots, each with the appropriate title (and not 16 plots that are each possible permutation of title and plot).

I've tried looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472019/add-titles-to-ggplots-created-with-map), but my titles are contained in another vector. This [post](https://aosmith.rbind.io/2018/08/20/automating-exploratory-plots/) got me as far as I have so far.

Here's my data and vector of titles:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- tibble(s1 = c("Agree", "Neutral", "Strongly Disagree"),
               s2rl = c("Agree", "Neutral", "Strongly Disagree"),
               f1 = c("Strongly Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree"),
               f2rl = c("Strongly Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree"))

titles <- c("S1 results", "Results for S2RL", "Fiscal Results for F1", "Financial Status of F2RL")
```

And here's the custom function that I'm building that takes 2 inputs, the variable and the title (the dataset is hardcoded in), and my map function that does not work:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

my_plots = function(variable) {
  test %>%
    count({{variable}}) %>%
    mutate(percent = 100*(n / sum(n, na.rm = T))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = {{variable}}, y = percent, fill = {{variable}})) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    ylab("Percentage") +
    ggtitle(paste(title, "N =", n)) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Strongly disagree" = "#CA001B", "Disagree" = "#1D28B0", "Neutral" = "#D71DA4", "Agree" = "#00A3AD", "Strongly agree" = "#FF8200")) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Strongly disagree" = "Strongly\nDisagree", "Disagree" = "Disagree", "Neutral" = "Neutral", "Agree" = "Agree", "Strongly agree" = "Strongly\nAgree"), drop = FALSE) + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 9, color = "gray28", face = "bold", hjust = .5),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, color = "gray32", face = "bold"),
          legend.position = "none",
          text = element_text(family = "Arial"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "gray32", face = "bold", hjust = .5)) +
    ylim(0, 100)
}

test%>%
  map(~my_plots(variable = .x, titles))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) instead of `{{}}` or use `.data`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
my_plots = function(variable, title) {
  test %>%
    count(!! rlang::sym(variable)) %>%
    mutate(percent = 100*(n / sum(n, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = !! rlang::sym(variable), y = percent, fill = .data[[variable]])) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    ylab("Percentage") +
    ggtitle(title) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Strongly disagree" = "#CA001B", "Disagree" = "#1D28B0", "Neutral" = "#D71DA4", "Agree" = "#00A3AD", "Strongly agree" = "#FF8200")) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Strongly disagree" = "Strongly\nDisagree", "Disagree" = "Disagree", "Neutral" = "Neutral", "Agree" = "Agree", "Strongly agree" = "Strongly\nAgree"), drop = FALSE) + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 9, color = "gray28", face = "bold", hjust = .5),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, color = "gray32", face = "bold"),
          legend.position = "none",
          text = element_text(family = "Arial"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 14, color = "gray32", face = "bold", hjust = .5)) +
    ylim(0, 100)
}
```

Then loop over the column names and titles in `map2` and apply the function

```
out <- map2(names(test), titles, ~ my_plots(variable = .x, title = .y))
ggarrange(plotlist = out, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: thank you! One question, in my original title, I wanted it to have the name and the sample size n. When I try your code but add in my original paste argument in ggtitle, I get this error--any ideas?         Error in paste(title, "n", n) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: @J.Sabree That part I am not sure what you really wanted beacuse `n` is a vector of values, you may need to collapse or take the first one

Comment: I'll try collapsing. In my actual data, some survey responses have NAs, so I wanted to show the number of non-missing responses. In this example, they'd all be 3, but in the real one they will almost certainly vary. Thanks again!

Comment: @J.Sabree Also, when you try with `ggtitle`, the `n` may not be available as such.  You may need `toString(unique(.data[["n"]]))` or so.  I haven't tested it