# Why does r purrr's pmap say "Only strings can be converted to symbols" and not iterate over dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr, pmap

I'm trying to automate my creation of ggplot slides using pmap from the purrr package. As an extension of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824617/how-to-use-map-and-ggplot-to-add-custom-titles-to-each-chart), I'm trying to facet based on the group membership variables in my data (level and location).

Unlike the previous question, I know have 3 inputs, so I need to use pmap() instead of map2(), and for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

And when I do dig into the error, it shows the problem is in my first pmap() call:

```
<error/rlang_error>
Only strings can be converted to symbols
Backtrace:
  1. purrr::pmap(...)
 14. rlang::sym(variable)
```

I've tried every combination, but I can't crack it. I want R to iterate every plot by level and location.

Here's my code and data:

```
#Packages
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

#Data
test <- tibble(s1 = c("Agree", "Neutral", "Strongly disagree"),
               s2rl = c("Agree", "Neutral", "Strongly disagree"),
               f1 = c("Strongly agree", "Disagree", "Strongly disagree"),
               f2rl = c("Strongly agree", "Disagree", "Strongly disagree"),
               level = c("Manager", "Employee", "Employee"),
               location = c("USA", "USA", "AUS"))

#Get just test items for name
test_items <- test %>%
  dplyr::select(s1, s2rl, f1, f2rl)

#titles of plots for R to iterate over
titles <- c("S1 results", "Results for S2RL", "Fiscal Results for F1", "Financial Status of F2RL")


#group levels
group_name <- c("level", "location")

#custom ggplot function
faceted_plots = function(variable, group, title) {

  sample_size <- test %>%
    group_by(!! rlang::sym(group), !! rlang::sym(variable)) %>%
    summarize(n = sum(!is.na(!! rlang::sym(variable))))
  

  test %>%
    count(!! rlang::sym(group), !! rlang::sym(variable)) %>%
    mutate(percent = 100*(n / sample_size$n)) %>%
    drop_na() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = !! rlang::sym(variable), y = percent, fill = .data[[variable]])) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label= paste0(percent, "%"), fontface = "bold", family = "Arial", size=14), vjust= 0, hjust = -.5) +
    ylab("\nPercentage") +
    labs(
      title = title,
      subtitle = paste0("(N = ", sample_size$n, ")")) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Strongly disagree" = "#CA001B", "Disagree" = "#1D28B0", "Neutral" = "#D71DA4", "Agree" = "#00A3AD", "Strongly agree" = "#FF8200")) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Strongly disagree" = "Strongly\nDisagree", "Disagree" = "Disagree", "Neutral" = "Neutral", "Agree" = "Agree", "Strongly agree" = "Strongly\nAgree"), drop = FALSE) + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = "gray28", face = "bold", hjust = .5),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 18, color = "gray32", face = "bold"),
          legend.position = "none",
          text = element_text(family = "Arial"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 20, color = "gray32", face = "bold", hjust = .5),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 16, color = "gray32", face = "bold", hjust = .5),
          panel.spacing.x = unit(2, "lines")) +
    ylim(0, 100) +
    facet_grid(~!! rlang::sym(group))
}

#pmap call
plots_and_facet <- pmap(
  list(x = names(test_items),
       y= titles,
       z = group_name),
  faceted_plots(test_items, titles, group_name))
```

EDIT with Mr. Flick's solution--it works! Disregard any of the issues with the counting, as that was on my end and is out of scope for this question:

```
#custom ggplot function
faceted_plots = function(variable, group, title) {

  sample_size <- test %>%
    group_by(.data[[group]], .data[[variable]]) %>%
    summarize(n = sum(!is.na(.data[[variable]])))
  

  test %>%
    count(.data[[group]], .data[[variable]]) %>%
    mutate(percent = 100*(n / sample_size$n)) %>%
    drop_na() %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = .data[[variable]], y = percent, fill = .data[[variable]])) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(aes(label= paste0(percent, "%"), fontface = "bold", family = "Arial", size=14), vjust= 0, hjust = -.5) +
    ylab("\nPercentage") +
    labs(
      title = title,
      subtitle = paste0("(N = ", sample_size$n, ")")) +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Strongly disagree" = "#CA001B", "Disagree" = "#1D28B0", "Neutral" = "#D71DA4", "Agree" = "#00A3AD", "Strongly agree" = "#FF8200")) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Strongly disagree" = "Strongly\nDisagree", "Disagree" = "Disagree", "Neutral" = "Neutral", "Agree" = "Agree", "Strongly agree" = "Strongly\nAgree"), drop = FALSE) + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = "gray28", face = "bold", hjust = .5),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size = 18, color = "gray32", face = "bold"),
          legend.position = "none",
          text = element_text(family = "Arial"),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 20, color = "gray32", face = "bold", hjust = .5),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 16, color = "gray32", face = "bold", hjust = .5),
          panel.spacing.x = unit(2, "lines")) +
    ylim(0, 100) +
    facet_grid(~.data[[group]])
}

#pmap call
expand_grid(tibble(item = names(test_items), title=titles),
              group = group_name) %>%
  pmap(function(item, group, title)
    faceted_plots(item, group, title))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `pmap` you actually need to pass a function, not call a function for the `.f=` parameter. Also if you want all possible combinations of things, you'll first need to create the combinations with `purrr::expand_grid` before calling `pmap`. So your call would look something like

```
plots_and_facet <-
  expand_grid(tibble(item = names(test_items), title=titles),
              group = group_name) %>%
  pmap(function(item, group, title)
    faceted_plots(item, group, title))
```

Also you have a bunch of useages of `!!rlang::sym(variable)` but the recommended way to do this now is `.data[[variable]]` which you do have in some places, but you should just change all those to use the `.data` pronoun to be safe.

Comment: thanks for your help! Your solution makes the code run, but there's one issue. It's not iterating over all the titles and is just using the first one. I edited my question to include your solution along with it's code--can you identify why it won't iterate through the titles?

Comment: Did you update the part of the code that said `labs(title = "Test")`? Make sure you are using the value passed to the `title` parameter: `labs(title = title)`

Comment: yes I edited that part once I implemented your solution which is how I discovered it’s only using “S1 Results” for all charts

Comment: Your code has `lab(title = titles)`, not `lab(title = title)`. The former uses the global variable with all the values and the latter uses the value passed to the function.

Comment: that's exactly what it was--thanks! I've edited my code to reflect the change and will accept the answer. I appreciate your time!