# Add title to ggplot objects in function that will be used with map()

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, purrr

I have a function that does several things including produce ggplot objects. I then pass this function to purrr::map() to iterate over nested data. I need to add an `id` as a `ggtitle` to each `ggplot` object in my function, but the `ggplot` objects are created by another function from another R package, so I have to add the `ggtitle` AFTER the `ggplot` object is created in my function. When I try to iterate using `purrr::map()` I get an error.

I think this thread might be helpful, but I couldn't figure out how to code it for my example: [Add titles to ggplots created with map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472019/add-titles-to-ggplots-created-with-map)

Here is a very simplified function that I think replicates my issue:

```
library("tidyverse")

dat <- 
  structure(list(id = c("07060710", "07060710", "07060710", "07060710", 
  "07060710", "07060710", "07060710", "07060710", "07060710", "07060710", 
  "07263295", "07263295", "07263295", "07263295", "07263295", "07263295", 
  "07263295", "07263295", "07263295", "07263295"), y = c(-0.1, 
  0.1, 0, 0, -0.1, -0.1, -0.1, 0, -0.1, -0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
  0.9, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 0.4, 0.4), x = c(1, 1.8, 1.3, 1.3, 0.7, 0.3, 
  1.5, 0.9, 1, 0.5, 1.1, 1, -0.1, -0.4, 3.2, 2.4, 3, 3.3, 0.7, 
  1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
  -20L))

runLM = function(df) {
  # Here I try to extract the id
  # And I think this is what causes the error
  id_title <- unique(df$id)
  
  lm_fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
  
  # This is a simplified plot function for this example
  # The actual initial plot is created by a function from another package
  # So I cannot manipulate the initial ggplot function
  # I can only manipulate the ggplot object after it is created
  plot_init <- 
    df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()
  
  # Here I try to add the 'id' as a the plot title
  plot_fin <- plot_init +
    ggtitle(id_title)
  
  return(plot_fin)
}
```

I then pass this function along to:

```
fit_lm <-
  dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~runLM(df = .x)))

# Here should be the plot, but I get an error when I try to iterate using map()
fit_lm[[3]][[1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After nesting there is no column `id` in the dataframes stored in the list column `data`. Instead add an argument `id_title` to your function and use `map2` to loop over both the `id` and  the `data` column of your nested data:

```r
library("tidyverse")
runLM = function(df, id_title) {
  lm_fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
  
  plot_init <- 
    df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point()
  
  plot_fin <- plot_init +
    ggtitle(id_title)
  
  return(plot_fin)
}

fit_lm <- dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map2(data, id, ~runLM(df = .x, id_title = .y)))

fit_lm$model
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is *not to nest*, but use `group_split` instead. Then you can use your original function without a second argument.

Also no need to use mutate.

```r
dat %>% 
  group_split(id) %>% 
  map(runLM)
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice and a good reminder. I'm so used to `nest/split`+ `map/lapply` that I always forget that `dplyr` now offers some options for these use cases, too. (:

Comment: @tjebo You can call `map(runLM)` instead of `map(~runLM(df = .x))`.

Comment: @jpdugo17 of course. good point and thanks! makes it much neater syntax.